# What is the actual raw integer value of UIBackgroundTaskInvalid?

Tags: ios, uikit

I am currently working in Xamarin iOS where I don't have access to the following constant:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibackgroundtaskidentifier/1622983-invalid

I would like to be able to default my task ID variable to the invalid constant value and also be able to check the return value of `beginBackgroundTask` to ensure that the value returned is valid.

Would anyone be able to help me out? I understand the value may change in future versions of iOS, but I can always update my code accordingly in the future.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The raw value is 0.
That is the full answer, but it is too short for StackOverflow so:

```swift
assert(UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier.invalid.rawValue == 0)
```

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate it.